# test the call to Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I have a menu item that when clicked, call the `ACTION_SEND`, like this

```
public static void shareToGMail(Context context, String subject, String content) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, Constants.FEEDBACK_EMAIL);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);

    // Attach Debug log:
    File dataDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File logFile = new File(dataDirectory, Constants.LOG_FILENAME);
    if (logFile.exists() && logFile.canRead()) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + logFile);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    } else {
        Timber.e("Could not attach Debug file, file " + Constants.BAMBAM_LOG_FILENAME + " does not exist or cannot be read");
    }

    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
    ResolveInfo best = null;
    for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail"))
            best = info;
    if (best != null)
        emailIntent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
    context.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

I'm trying to test this, with this code

```
    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFeedback(){
        try {
            openDrawer(R.id.drawer_layout);
            onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).check(matches(isOpen()));

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//            intentFilter.addDataType("text/plain");

            Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor receiverActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(intentFilter, null, false);

            onView(allOf(withText(R.string.report_issues))).perform(click());
            Activity sendActivity = receiverActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(1000);

            assertNotNull(sendActivity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
    }
```

but I get `NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity`, but I'm calling `getActivity()` on my setup method...what is missing?

Comment: will try that! thanks

Comment: Android emulator comes with the email client. Can you share your setup code please? And the rule that you are using.

Comment: @Be_Negative just edited the question. the whole code to send email is there

Comment: @LuizE. Oops, sorry, I was wondering about your test setUp() method and activity rule that you are using in your tests, not the actual production code.

Comment: @Be_Negative edited, but I dont know what is activity rule

Comment: @luize Does your test fail right away? Or does it fail after it clicks on the share? In your initial question you were using Espresso Intents, but you never called [init](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/Intents.html#init()) which means that your intent was never caught by Espresso. If my assumption is correct, your test opened the intent app and died there as it requires your application to be foregrounded to continue. Rules are described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/JUnit4RulesInATSL) .

Comment: My test fail on the `assertNotNull(sendActivity);` because at that point, `sendActivity` is null...I'll give it a read on the links you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espresso Intents ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/matcher/IntentMatchers.html), [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/rule/IntentsTestRule)) is made for this:

```
@Rule
public final ActivityRule<MyActivity> rule = new ActivityRule<>(MyActivity.class);

@Test
public void testFeedback() {
    openDrawer(R.id.drawer_layout);
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).check(matches(isOpen()));
    onView(allOf(withText(R.string.report_issues))).perform(click());

    intended(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND));
}
```

plus static imports, minus syntax errors.